# How to handle firefox browser downloads window using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs, slimerjs

how do you manage the download window firefox? I mean the scenario is:I have created on notebook and i want to export that notebook as a file with the single click option like `this.click({type:'css', path:"#export_notebook"});`but it is getting stuck when firefox throws the download window(whether to open/save the file). how to handle that window?
and please Let me know the solution

Comment: Do you know solution for it @Artjom B

Comment: No, I don't use SlimerJS.